# How to swipe for next item in ListView / RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

In Gmail app when you click on an email, that particular email opens and swiping left and right opens previous or next email respectively.

I want to do the same thing in my app, what i have done is:

1.Made an *sqlite* database and using **SimpleCursorAdapter** to populate the **ListView**

2.ListView **onItemClickListener** opens an Activity which has a *ViewPager* and with the help of it i am setting a Fragment.

```
public class PagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager pager;
FragmentPagerAdapter adapter;
Toolbar toolbar;
Bundle b;
Long id;
int count;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide_pager);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    b=getIntent().getExtras();
    id=b.getLong("id");
    count=b.getInt("count");
    adapter=new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),id,count);
    pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pagerAdapter);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

3.I am also getting the row count using `cursor.getCount()` and passing it to **FragmentPagerAdapter** which in turn set the number of swipe-able Views/Fragments.

4.This is working fine but if i click the item number *5* in ListView, i can swipe to *6,7..* but can't swipe back to *4*.

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
Long id;
int count;
Bundle b;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Long mId,int mCount) {
    super(fm);
    this.id=mId;
    this.count=mCount;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    b=new Bundle();
    b.putInt("position",position);
    b.putLong("id", id);
    b.putInt("count",count);
    PageFragment PageFragment=new PageFragment();
    pageFragment.setArguments(b);
    return pageFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

}

If need be, i am ready to switch to RecyclerView from ListView but i wanted to know if this can work? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yepp launching an Activity on Listitem click and then using a FragmentPagerAdapter along with a Viewpager will work. I've implemented it personally as well.

Comment: I said that it is working, you didn't get my question. Read 4th point again.

Comment: My point is there is nothing wrong with the implementation and it should work you should check your fragment if it is updating data correctly.